# Cursor that fetches the values of one column in a table is not displaying correctly

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a following function with a cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LONGTRIP 
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR 
AS t_driver SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
    OPEN t_driver FOR
    SELECT TOTALTRIPMADE
    FROM DRIVER;

    RETURN t_driver;
END;
/
```

The cursor in the function is supposed to fetch all values from the TOTALTRIPMADE column in the DRIVER table.

Then I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT E#, LONGTRIP AS TOTALTRIPMADE
FROM DRIVER;
```

It is supposed to display the column E# and TOTALTRIPMADE together, but instead I get this:

```
        E# TOTALTRIPMADE                                                                            
---------- --------------------                                                                     
         1 CURSOR STATEMENT : 2                                                                     

CURSOR STATEMENT : 2

TOTALTRIPMADE                                                                                       
-------------                                                                                       
            1                                                                                       




            2                                                                                       
            1                                                                                       

7 rows selected.
```

Instead what I want is:

```
 E#               TOTALTRIPMADE                                                                            
---------- --------------------                                                                     
         1                    2    
         3                    1
         5                    0
```

As the TOTALTRIPMADE can be null, how do I program it such that 0 will appear instead of it being blank?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what are you trying to achieve? are you trying to output the total trips made for each of the driver? if the case, then this can be done as a simple aggregation grouping by E#. Instead, how the code is written, for each entry in the table you open a new cursor that fetches each entry again

Comment: Are you running the select statement from SQL prompt? If not provide the details of the pl/sql block? AFAIK if you are running from SQL prompt it should error ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got CURSOR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below function, your function doesn't have input parameter for E#. You don't need a refcursor infact to return value from a column.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LONGTRIP(ehash IN varchar2)
RETURN DRIVER.TOTALTRIPMADE%TYPE 
AS t_driver DRIVER.TOTALTRIPMADE%TYPE;

BEGIN

    SELECT NVL(TOTALTRIPMADE,0) INTO t_driver
    FROM DRIVER where E#= ehash;

    RETURN t_driver;

    EXCEPTION 
      WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

Your select statement has to be modified as below to pass E# as input parameter to the function,

```
SELECT E#, LONGTRIP(E#) AS TOTALTRIPMADE
FROM DRIVER;
```

Comment: hmm, edited my code and it didnt work! i still got the same results as before :/

Comment: Modified the code, do you really need refcursor here? Are you expecting more than one row to be returned from driver for an E#?

Comment: ahh i got the expected output now from your code! thank you!